# ssh команды с openwrt <-> serial <-> arduino

Tags: terminal, arduino, openwrt

Необходимо при нажатии кнопки ардуины выводить на ее же дисплей информацию взятую из sqlite базы лежащей на oenwrt.
Рассматривал сеть но лепить лишний eth sield решил что лишнее.
Решаю сделать по serial (USB) через встроенный в arduino serial порт.
Вопрос.
Смогу ли я скажем послать с ардуины запрос вида 
sqlite3 base.sql SELECT * FROM table1 WERE para=1
И получить ответ по serial и отправить на дисплей.
Интересует именно выполнение команд и обмен данными в пределах tty.

(мусор загрузок по ttl будет фильтроваться)

Comment: если захотите, то — да, сможете.

Comment: Обмен данными идет, да только bash не исполняется

Comment: *bash*-а там и не должно быть — слишком «жирен» он для тех устройств, где обычно устанавливают *openwrt*.

Comment: вот [это](http://autohome.org.ua/17-arduino/38-connect-arduino-to-router-openwrt), например, не читали?

Answer (score 2):

Запрос послать конечно можно, но с другой стороны его должны принять, обработать, послать ответ. То есть на openwrt должна крутиться программа и смотреть в tty.
Если хотите дать для Ардуины shell и чтоб она сама там командовала, то смотрите в сторону getty.

ИМХО проще написать скрипт, который будет смотреть в Serial, принимать команды, выдавать ответы.

Answer (score 0):

У Ардуино очень маленькая память программ, чтобы подобную функциональность прошивать в её чип. И чтобы Ардуино мог отправлять хосту shell-запросы, потребуется Ethernet или WiFi подключение.